# Replace value using value from other field

Tags: apache-pig

I have a problem that i need to replace string based on other field.

sample data:

```
field1|field2
1 x|x 
1 x|z
2 p|p
2 z|p
```

required output:

```
field1|field2
1|x
1 x|z
2|p
2 z|p
```

i have tried the following but doesn't work (no error simply doesn't do anything)

```
a = LOAD '$path'
                USING PigStorage('|')
                AS (
                field1:chararray,
                field2:chararray
                );  

b = foreach a generate
REPLACE(field1,field2,'') as field1,
field2;
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the required output is supposed to be ? It looks like you only want to change every second row, and remove the second/third char of the first field

Comment: I would like to replace a string based on other field. If field1 contains field2 then replace that string with null otherwise do nothing. so i need a simple replace function but instead using hardcoded "oldstring" i need to have it dynamic and the value is in field2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE` takes a regular expression so you need to construct that regular expression using `CONCAT`.

So a rather cumbersome solution is :

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
    REPLACE( field1, CONCAT ( CONCAT('(', field2), ')'), '')) as field1, field2;
```

so for the first row , the CONCAT will construct a regexp `'(x)'`

To get the output exactly like above I added a TRIM

B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
       TRIM(REPLACE( field1, CONCAT ( CONCAT('(', field2), ')'), '')) as field1, field2;

A better solution would be to write your own udf - then your pig code would be more readable

e.g

B = FOREACH A GENERATE MyReplaceWithBlank( field1, field2) as field1, field2;

see https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/udf.html#eval-functions

Comment: i have tried to pig version so far, and does not do the job all fields remains the same no replace.

Comment: It works for me with Pig 0.12.1. If you try without the CONCAT, e.g B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE( field1, '(x)','') as field1, field2; - do you get changed fields.

Comment: it works for a small example, i have problem somewhere else thanks

Comment: thanks Louise it works. i had another issue causing the problem.